# Android: Problem with opening a file located in the SD with InputStream

Tags: android, xml, inputstream

I want to parse an xml file located in the SD with an XMLReader

I have this code:

```
private RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
{
    try
    {
        // setup the url
       URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);

       // create the factory
       SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
       // create a parser
       SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

       // create the reader (scanner)
       XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
       // instantiate our handler
       RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();
       // assign our handler
       xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);
       // get our data through the url class
       InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
       // perform the synchronous parse           
       xmlreader.parse(is);
       // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, 
       // or null on error
       return theRssHandler.getFeed();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        // if you have a problem, simply return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

but this works for on-line xml files
what changes must be done in order to open an xml file stored in the SD card?

Comment: Check logcat for an error please, or log the error when you catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to your manifest file?

Comment: No, just added it. But what I really need is the code that will allow me to open a xml file stored in the SD in a way that is similar to the code above

Comment: what are you currently passing to this method?